# Match Color swatch requested by customer to sales in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, analytics

MY data is like below:

```
ID     Date         Swatch Name    Item Name
1      6/8/2019     Blue           Null
1      6/8/2019     Charcoal       Null
1      7/16/2019    Null           Ottoman - Charcoal
1      9/9/2019     Red            Null
1      3/20/2020    Grey           Null
1      6/1/2020     Null           Chair - Red
2      2/3/2016     Green          Null
3      4/7/2017     Pink           Null
3      5/6/2018     Lava           Null
3      8/12/2019    Null           Pillow - Pink
```

ID is customer ID

How do I match each swatch color with subsequent item bought by each customer to say that the swatch ordered is the color of item a customer bought in tableau.

what I would like is as below:

```
ID     Date         Swatch Name    Item Name             Conversion
1      6/8/2019     Blue           Null
1      6/8/2019     Charcoal       Null
1      7/16/2019    Null           Ottoman - Charcoal    Yes
1      9/9/2019     Red            Null
1      3/20/2020    Grey           Null
1      6/1/2020     Null           Chair - Red           Yes 
2      2/3/2016     Green          Null
2      3/15/2016    Null           Table - Brown         No 
3      4/7/2017     Pink           Null
3      5/6/2018     Lava           Null
3      8/12/2019    Null           Pillow - Pink         Yes
```

Comment: Please elaborate with an example or screenshot!  It is not clear what each row of record indicate? What is Id? How a customer is identified?

Comment: Can you share your .twbx here with sample data, please

Answer (score 0):

Please reshape your data in prep like this..

[image: preview]

thereafter compare Id+color combination counts with Id+swatch_or_Item+Color combination  counts